# Is this wiki article about vector spaces wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is from the article "Examples of vector spaces" on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_vector_spaces#Field

"The next simplest example is the field F itself. Vector addition is just field addition and scalar multiplication is just field multiplication... F has just two subspaces: {0} and F itself."

Here's my proposed counterexample: $\mathbb{R}^2$ has all vectors with the second component = 0 as a subspace. The article seems to be clearly wrong, but I just wanted to make sure since I haven't worked with vector spaces that generally before.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how what you wrote is a counter example?

Comment: I was under the impression that R^2 constituted a field, and so made a mistake

Comment: For R^2 to be a field there needs to be a multiplication defined on elements in R^2 which gets you another element of R^2. One way you could try to do this is by identifying R^2 with the complex plane C, and using multiplication of complex numbers as your field multiplication. In this case C is a field, and C is a vector space over C, but C has just two subspaces {0} and C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}^2$ is not a field, therefore not a valid counterexample.

Edit:

More precisely, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not a valid counterexample, because the vector-space structure you are assuming is $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a two-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, whereas the example is of a field viewed as a vector space over itself, which is always one-dimensional. See also Zorngo's comment.

Comment: Could you point out which field axiom R^2 violates?

Comment: (im thinking of regular real addition and multiplication done pointwise for the operations)

Comment: @user52969 What multiplication does $\Bbb R^2$ *classically* have?

Comment: With point-wise multiplication any vector with a zero in one of its coordinates is not invertable. In a field every non-zero element must be invertable.

Comment: @user52969  Zorngo has already answered that question. Specifically, when you give the span of $(1,0)$ as an example of a subspace, you are assuming that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, and in particular, two dimensional, whereas a field viewed as a vector space over itself is always one-dimensional.